# How can I modify my html truncate function to allow links and spans?

Tags: javascript

I am currently using the following function to truncate the text content of certain elements that may or may not contain other elements such as `<a>` or `<span>`.

Having previous tried several regex based solutions, I have settled on this method since it is infinitely faster and more reliable.

However, I would like any `<span>` or `<a>` elements to remain intact in the overall output, even if their contents are truncated.  Right now since I am currently only filtering through text nodes, this is not possible.

Is there anyway I could modify the function below to keep the aforementioned elements intact?

```
var cloneNode = rootNode.cloneNode(true);
var currentNode = cloneNode;
var ni = document.createNodeIterator(currentNode, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT);
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
var len = 0;
var max = 300;



while (currentNode = ni.nextNode()) {
    if (currentNode.parentNode === cloneNode) {
        if (len + currentNode.textContent.length > max){
            currentNode.textContent = currentNode.textContent.substring(0, max - len).replace(/\s*$/,"");

            var ellipsis = document.createElement('span');
            ellipsis.classList.add('inline_ellipsis');
            ellipsis.appendChild(document.createTextNode('... '));


            var seeMore = document.createElement('button');
            seeMore.classList.add('comment_truncated');
            seeMore.appendChild(document.createTextNode('See more'));


            frag.appendChild(currentNode);
            frag.appendChild(ellipsis);
            frag.appendChild(seeMore);

            self.truncatedElement = rootNode;

            break;
        }
        else{
            frag.appendChild(currentNode);
        }
    }
    else{
        frag.appendChild(currentNode.parentNode);
    }
    len += currentNode.textContent.length;
}

rootNode.setAttribute('data-fullcontent', rootNode.innerHTML);

rootNode.innerHTML = '';
rootNode.appendChild(frag);

rootNode.setAttribute('data-truncatedcontent', rootNode.innerHTML);
```

Comment: Maybe better for code review over stack overflow?

Comment: Wow, "infinitely", `(new_performance - old_performance) / old_performance * 100%`

Comment: Lol, As i'm sure you're aware, the term 'infinitely' is being used as a figure of speech. :p  Regardless, performance using a regex solution is noticeably poor and with the amount of work I am having to do each time, ruins the user experience due to main thread blocking.